# Handling the TAB character in Java

Tags: java, string, character

I'm going through a configuration file with a RandomAccessFile reader. I have a configuration option which is one (1) tab away from the start of the line. When my reader gets this line, would I be able to just tell it to skip one character and then start reading, or does the tab character not work that way?

Example:

```
This is a line
        This line has a tab
```

Let's say I've loaded the second line into my reader. If I'm playing with that String and I do `currentLine = currentLine.subString(1);`

Would that give me:

```
currentLine = "This line has a tab";
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Because I figured someone else might google this and find a link to this question. I wasn't going to ask if it was already on the site. After all, we are supposed to be aggregating information. Thanks for your help below.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Yes the tab character is one character. You can match it in java with "\t".

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the tab character `'\t'` to represent a tab, instead of `"\t"`.

```
char c ='\t'; // tabulator
char c =(char)9; // tabulator
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you could just perform a `trim()` on the string to handle the case when people use spaces instead of tabs (unless you are reading makefiles)